# How can I change before update trigger to before insert trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table and this table must have at most 1000 row. When user wants to add 1001st row, there must be an error. I know i should use insert trigger. I'm a new person in SQL can you help me?

My code is:

```
create or replace trigger update_ext_app_serv
before update on EXTERNAL_APP_SERVICE
for each row

declare
  row_count number;
  old_service_id number;
  new_service_trigger varchar(30);
  old_service_trigger varchar(30);
begin
  row_count := 0;
  new_service_trigger := :NEW.TRIGGER_NAME;
  old_service_trigger := :OLD.TRIGGER_NAME;
  old_service_id := :OLD.SERVICE_ID;

  select count(*) into row_count 
  from EXTERNAL_APP_PROFILE 
  where ORIG_ID = old_service_id 
  or TERM_FAILURE_RESP_ID = old_service_id 
  or TERM_ID = old_service_id;

  if (row_count > 0) and (new_service_trigger not like old_service_trigger) 
  then
      raise_application_error(-20706, 'Unable to update Trigger. The service is referenced at least External Application Profile.');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Re-tagged with `oracle` and `plsql` based on the syntax in the question

Comment: I think that first at all you have to change your trigger for `before insert` after all you want the error message when someone tries to insert the rows.

Comment: Not sure what this trigger has to do with anything, but it seems to be enforcing a foreign key, You should use a foreign key constraint to do that. Triggers are inefficient and also don't work in concurrent environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with an AFTER trigger, and at the statement rather than row level.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t1000_trg
  2  after insert on t1000
  3  declare
  4      n pls_integer;
  5  begin
  6      select count(*) into n
  7      from t1000;
  8      if n > 1000 then
  9          raise_application_error(-20999, 'No more than 1000 records!');
 10      end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.
SQL>
```

Here's our test data.

```
SQL> select count(*) from t1000;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       999

SQL>
```

1000th record okay...

```
SQL> insert into t1000 values (1000);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

... but 1001st record is rejected:

```
SQL> insert into t1000 values (1001);
insert into t1000 values (1001)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20999: No more than 1000 records!
ORA-06512: at "FOX.T1000_TRG", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FOX.T1000_TRG'

SQL>
```

Works for multi-row insert statements too.

```
SQL> roll
Rollback complete.
SQL> select count(*) from t1000;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       999

SQL> insert into t1000 select 1000 + level from dual connect by level <= 5;
insert into t1000 select 1000 + level from dual connect by level <= 5
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20999: No more than 1000 records!
ORA-06512: at "FOX.T1000_TRG", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FOX.T1000_TRG'


SQL>
```